# Is Facebook Recommendations Bar available for non-developer users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-recommendations

Is the [recommendations bar](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendationsbar/) available to general users? I have it installed it on one of our websites, but no one other than the developers & testers of the app can see it. I already checked that we have sandbox setting disabled. Am I missing something or are they just not yet available to other FB developers or users?

Comment: I wish they would release this plugin for everyone already, they seem to be taking a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct -- it's not currently available to users.

Answer (score 3):

Now it's no longer Beta and everybody can use it.They officially announced today.
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/07/26/introducing-the-recommendations-bar/ 
I saw its documentation page is moved from "Beta plugins" section to "Plugins" section on the left navigation.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendationsbar/ 
You can logout from Facebook and still see the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I was trying this case and the result was alway ERROR! We must wait for this function enabled for all fan?? (not admin)